# Javascript customer data, options is undefined in Firefox

Tags: magento2, javascript, customer-data

I have tis issue with the customer-data Javascript object.
Her is (a par of my code)

```
define([
    'jquery',
    "Magento_Customer/js/customer-data"

], function ($, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return function (config, element) {
        customerData.reload(customerData.getExpiredSectionNames(), true).then(
            function () {
                let group = customerData.get('customer')();
                //do stuff after getting customer data
            }
        );
    }
});
```

I now the code can be approved by checking if the customer section needs a reload, but that is not the problem.

The code works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox I get the following error:
`TypeError: options is undefined`

The options get used in the getExpiredSectionNames() function on following line:

```
sectionLifetime = options.expirableSectionLifetime * 60
```

I guess this has to do with loading order of the javascript files. 
So I tried moving the `customer.customer.data` block in de default.xml but that didn't work either.

Is there a way I can insert the options in the customer-data object from my custom js script? Or do I need to add somthing in my requirjs-config.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer. It was because I didn't add my dependencies in requirejs file.

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        custom_js: 'js/custom',
    },
    shim: {
        custom_js: ['jquery', 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data']
    },
}
```

I still find it strange that Chrome did load the dependencies correctly, but I'm happy I found a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have an error in your `customer/section/load` endpoint.
What does return http://your-localhost/customer/section/load ?

Comment: First, thanks for the info I didn't know you could view customer data from this url. Secondly, it shows the data correctly so that is not the problem.